# What could cause php.ini to ignore error_reporting directive?

Tags: php, error-reporting

So when I set this directive in php.ini

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

I still get these errors even after apache reload or reboot.

> Thu Sep 13 10:51:10 2012] [error] [client 173.59.22.4] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in

etc etc etc.

Any ideas? I am not sure why php.ini will not listen to this directive to not list deprecated.

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2012 16:53:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: Yeah, not figuring this out at all.

Comment: I think i figured it out, Backupbuddy had an error log setting that was affecting this for some reason. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

This took me ages to debug. Code generated by an old version of phprunner which was crashing because of "Deprecated function mysql_connect. But whatever I did with error_reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED); // was being ignored
```

It was because the code was using its own error handling function "error handler"

```
set_error_handler("my_error_handler"); // override error_reporting()
```

All I had to do was add the following line to function my_error_handler()

```
if ($errno==8192) return 0;   // ignore Deprecated
```

I wasted ages fiddling with my php.ini but it had nothing to do with it!

Answer (score 1):

error_reporting could've been called somewhere in your script.

you can use this to reset it before the error occurs:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: This is wordpress, where else could it be. It is not in .htaccess.

Comment: lots of places inside wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was the same as zzapper - the file name for phprunner is `phpfunctions.php` and this worked:

```
if ($errno==8192) return 0;   // ignore Deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several places](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) from which the value of this setting can be changed, including the quite commonly seen `ini_set` and `error_reporting` functions. Someone is changing it from one of them.

Comment: Is there a way I can run a search on the server to find another instance of the setting?

Comment: `-ri` would be perhaps better; function names in PHP are case-insensitive so someone could theoretically have written `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL)`.

Comment: The problem is, the query is never ending